# live streaming video goes black when there is no activity on the web-page

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, detach, hls.js

I am working on a website which has bunch of live streaming videos in it. After certain time(minutes) of inactivity in the browser,  **couple of live streaming videos goes black and have to refresh the page or scroll up/down in order to make it work**.

The HTML code which is being used in order to generate live streaming video at the front-end is:

```
<div class="h264-live-view embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" data-media-type="video" data-media-playback="play">
   <video poster="./images/000000-0.png" 
    src="./geb5ac04-8f4e-462a-5fef-abc"></video> // placed a break-point here
</div>
```

On **placing a break-point above on video tag**, line#A is called from the code below from [hls.js](https://video-dev.github.io/hls.js/stable/api-docs/file/src/controller/buffer-controller.js.html)

```
 if (this.media) {
    URL.revokeObjectURL(this._objectUrl);

    // clean up video tag src only if it's our own url. some external libraries might
    // hijack the video tag and change its 'src' without destroying the Hls instance first
    if (this.media.src === this._objectUrl) {
      this.media.removeAttribute('src');   // line#A
      this.media.load();
    } else {
      logger["b" /* logger */].warn('media.src was changed by a third party - skip cleanup');
    }
  }
```

The code which I am using in hls.js is present here https://video-dev.github.io/hls.js/stable/api-docs/file/src/controller/buffer-controller.js.html

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what can be the reason behind the **black screen of the live streaming video when there is no activity on the webpage for few mins** and how I can fix it.

Is there any way we can fix that bug ? Is there any code which I can override in order to fix this bug ? Also the question is  why `onMediaDetaching ()` function is called ? On placing a breakpoint on video tag as mentioned above, line#A `(this.media.removeAttribute('src');)` is called.

Comment: The code you posted is reasonable, the question is why is `onMediaDetaching` being called? This is difficult to investigate in the abstract. Please create a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us to look at and debug.

Comment: @OldPro Yeah that's right. Its very hard to create a fiddle and replicate it as there is tonnes of code involve in it. Is there anything wrong in this [file](https://video-dev.github.io/hls.js/stable/api-docs/file/src/controller/buffer-controller.js.html) ? As I am using the whole code from there. Let me know your thoughts.

Comment: @OldPro Line#145 is called from this code https://video-dev.github.io/hls.js/stable/api-docs/file/src/controller/buffer-controller.js.html as soon as the video goes off.  I have put the break point on video tag in html.

Comment: I cannot evaluate that one file in isolation. If I had to guess, I would guess your problem is probably due to the browser trying to save energy by shutting down what it thinks are unnecessary widgets. Do you have `auto-recover` enabled? See if you can reproduce your problem by plugging your video stream into the [`hls.js` demo page](https://video-dev.github.io/hls.js/stable/demo/). If you can, then [open an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/issues). Otherwise, the problem is how you are using the library.

Comment: @OldPro I have open an issue on Github. Here is the [link](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/issues/2038).  I am wondering how I can plugin my video stream [here](https://video-dev.github.io/hls.js/stable/demo/) ?

Comment: Enter the URL for your stream in the box above "Enable Streaming"

Comment: @OldPro Its an internal website where I have to enter my credentials and see the live streaming. Its not a youtube website where you don't have to enter the credentials to see the link.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185023/discussion-between-john-and-old-pro).